# XML Deserialisation and XPath?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have Xml like so

```
            <pda:Party>
                 ...Snip....
                <pda:CitizenName>
                    <pda:CitizenNameTitle>MR</pda:CitizenNameTitle>
                    <pda:CitizenNameForename>John</pda:CitizenNameForename>
                    <pda:CitizenNameSurname>Wayne</pda:CitizenNameSurname>
                </pda:CitizenName>
              .....Snip...
           </pda:Party>
```

Where Citizen Name is a complex type within the Party Node. ( This is xml received from a 3rd party integration that I'm creating an adapter for )

I'm not interested that there is a sub type as in my class I'm attempting to deserialize into I would rather have.

```
public class Party
{
    public string  FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName {get;set;}

}
```

So rather than have my class definition as a concrete definition of what the XML represents, can I decorate the properties with something like XPath, eg.

```
 [XmlElement("\CitizenName\CitizenNameForeName")]
 public string FirstName {get;set;}
```

To cherry pick information from the xml into a class the contains the data i'm interested in?

The xml received from the 3rd party is very verbose and I'm only interested in specific aspects. One option is to just create an XMLDocument and map to my class manually using XPath and a conversion method, but I thought I would ask in case there was an intermediary solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I set up my own attribute to do what i wanted it to do. So a custom attribute that takes an XPath path...

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class PathToXmlNode : System.Attribute
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public PathToXmlNode(string path)
    {
        this.Path = path;
    }
}
```

followed by a decorated property.. ( namespaces omitted for simplicity )

```
         [PathToXmlNode("Party[1]/CitizenName/CitizenNameForename")]
         public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Then when i want to populate the class I called the following method.

```
        var type = typeof(T);
        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PathToXmlNode), true);

            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                //this property has this attribute assigned.
                //get the value to assign
                var xmlAttribute = (PathToXmlNode)attributes[0];
                var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(xmlAttribute.Path, nmgr);


                if (node != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.InnerText))
                {
                    dynamic castedValue;

                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                    {
                        castedValue = Convert.ToBoolean(node.InnerText);
                    }
                    ...Snip all the casts....
                    else
                    {
                        castedValue = node.InnerText;
                    }


                    //we now have the node and it's value, now set it to the property.
                    property.SetValue(obj, castedValue, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, null, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                }

            }
        }
```

This has been a good starting point, however If anyone else see's this as a viable intermediary solution, You need to be aware that it will need adapting for non simple data types. Which is what I'm setting off to do now!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an XSLT transform to parse the incoming XML into s format that matches your class.

Comment: I'm not fantastic at XSLT, I've dabbled before however due to the amount of XML that get's pulled back i'm not confident it would be a viable way of doing this with the time I've got. But thank you for the suggestion.