# Remove unnecessary nesting when deserializing XML or access data in parent node?

Tags: c#, xml

The XML I'm attempting to deserialize has a lot of fields that have the data nested in a subfield and I'd like to assign this data into the parent property on the class rather than create additional unneeded structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:EventRecord eventid="EVR-1000">
  <x:Postcode>
    <x:ID>ABC123</x:ID>
  </x:Postcode>
</x:EventRecord>
```

I've created an EventRecord class with a Postcode string property:

```
public class EventRecord
{
  public string EventID { get; set; }
  public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an attribute that can decorate the property that can tell the deserializer to take the value out of the nested `ID` field? There will never be any other fields in `<x:Postcode>` aside from `<x:ID>`.

Also is there a way to assign the `eventid` XML attribute on the parent `x:EventRecord` node to the `EventID` property inside itself?

Comment: Look  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123554/xml-deserialisation-and-xpath - seems like you can use xpath to specify nodes for properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:x="abc">
<x:EventRecord eventid="EVR-1000">
  <x:Postcode>
    <x:ID>ABC123</x:ID>
  </x:Postcode>
</x:EventRecord>
</root>
```

---

Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("x");

            EventRecord record = doc.Descendants(ns + "EventRecord").Select(x => new EventRecord() {
                EventID = (string)x.Attribute("eventid"),
                Postcode = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "ID").FirstOrDefault()
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
    public class EventRecord
    {
        public string EventID { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more integrated like an attribute decoration on the property but this will work for the time being. Thanks